# Style checkbox blue hover in Twitter Boostrap

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I can't seem to target the blue hover background of the checkboxes in Twitter Bootstrap. My project is in local dev but just look at any of the checkboxes on this page http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms - When I use Firebug to set them to hover they dont operate like normal hovers. I have tried Chrome dev tools also. I have also just tried styling them using

```
input[type="checkbox"] {

}
```

to target. I've tried affecting `background-color` and `box-shadow` (inset) and nothing seems to get rid of the blue.

Has anyone any experience of this?

**I am not asking [how to style checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css) and if that answer contains and answer for me apologies and please point it out. What I am asking is specific to Bootstrap. I am asking which attribute ( in bootsrap) the blue hue comes from.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style checkbox using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css)

Comment: I don't see how that question answers this directly.

Comment: Bootstrap uses the default, un-styled checkboxes that come with the browser. That questions directly answers your question.

Comment: thanks ... I hope you can see that information is needed on this question to make the other question an answer to this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Twitter Bootstrap attribute for this. It's just browser depended. Here, look at this simple checkbox. It have the same blue color on hover as it in Bootstrap.

```
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gjVm7/